# Unable to get JSON output from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json

I've read a few StackOverflow posts, googled it but still can't get what I want.

I simply want to get a JSON from Google's API and import it to a variable so I can filter it the way I want, the following code is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Term: <input type="text" id="field1" value="Mc Donalds in New York"><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>

<script>
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

function myFunction() {
    var termo = document.getElementById("field1").value;
    var URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query="+termo.replace(" ","+")+"&key=HIDDEN_KEY";
    var data = createCORSRequest('GET',URL);
    if (!data) {
      throw new Error('CORS not supported');
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I do:

```
console.log(data);
```

I get:

[image]

When I do:

```
JSON.parse(data.responseText);
```

I get:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from
>   'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's
>   'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'json').

What should I get on console.log:
https://pastebin.com/4H7MAMcM

How can I get the JSON from XMLHttpRequest correctly?

Also worth mentioning, I'm using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) because I couldn't access the domain from my local IP.

--Edit--
Phil thought this was a matter of not being able to return response from a asynchronous, but its wrong, I've tried using Ajax, XMLHttpRequest and now using CORS, the duplicate notation was incorrect, please remove it.

Comment: Is fetch an option instead of XMLHttprequest? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Fetch didn't do the job @mkaatman

Answer (score -1):

This behaviour [is documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText);

> If responseType is set to anything other than the empty string or "text", accessing responseText will throw InvalidStateError exception.

Instead, you need to use the [`response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) property. Since you specified `json` as the `responseType`, `response` will be a JavaScript object (no need to `JSON.parse` it).

Aside from this, you'll also need to treat the AJAX request as asynchronous, rather than synchronous. For more info on that, see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Eventually, you should end up with something like;

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url, cb) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
        cb(this.response);
      }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

createCORSRequest('POST', '/echo/json/', function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ez3xt6ys/

**However**, the browser support seems patchy for this at best; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response. Instead, it is more common to see the `responseType` being left as `text`, and for people to `JSON.parse()` the `responseText` property.